# Catalog search show all products - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

When I do a search it does not give me a result based on my input but it shows me the whole catalog.
 Which is a problem because my catalog contains over 85,000 products, and it takes a lot of time to load the search result.
 How can I adjust the search?

Comment: Please check : Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes >
here is many attributes are enable searchable you can disable it and also check in Admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search > change Search Type: Like to Full Text. then clear cache and reindex.